# ¿Como lograr que el contador me reste 1 número y no que me devuelva a la primera posicion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy creando dos botones de contador, **anterior** y **siguiente**, para que vaya de uno en uno y reste de uno en uno. Con el contador de **siguiente** logré hacerlo pero cuando clickeo el contador que va al **anterior**, cuando llega al final del numero que le pase en la condicion, me devuelve al comienzo, o sea `0`, y yo lo que quiero es que si esta en `3` me regrese a `2`, y así.

function ComponentesEstilizados() {

```
const inicial = 0
const max = 3

const MyButton = styled.button`
width: 50%;
`

let [contador, setContador] = useState(0);


let previousPhrase = () => {
    console.log(contador);
    contador > max ? setContador(contador - 1) : setContador (contador + 1)
    //(contador === 3  ) ? setContador(contador -1) : setContador(3); 
}  

let nextPhrase = () => {
    console.log(contador);
    contador < inicial ? setContador(contador + 1 ) : setContador (contador - 1)
    //(contador === 3 ) ? setContador(0) : setContador(++contador);
}  



return (
    <div>
        <MyButton onClick={ ()=> previousPhrase()}>Anterior</MyButton>
        <MyButton onClick={ () => nextPhrase()}>Siguiente</MyButton>
        
    </div>
)
```

}

export default ComponentesEstilizados

cuando hago console log, al llegar a 3, clickeo en anterior y me devuelve a 0.

Comment: es un código muy corto, pasa el componente para ver como lo estás armando y no queda claro en realidad como quieres que sea el comportamiento, pero con el código es más sencillo de ver, después no hay un criterio en el ++ y -- en uno delante, en otro detrás, lo ideal para aumentar o reducir un número en un state es poner por ej: setContador(prev=> prev + 1) o setContador(prev=> prev - 1).

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y coloca el código _en_ la pregunta. En los comentarios es ilegible.

Comment: ahi modifique la pregunta y esta todo el codigo, puedes verlo?

Answer (score 1):

Ahí está funcionando cíclicamente para ambos lados, saqué los console.log y muestro directamente el valor del contador en un div dentro del return.

Tanto las variables como las funciones no se modifican en ningún momento con "=" por lo que podés usar sin problema const.

Al llamar a las funciones en el onClick no es necesario usar arrow functions si no precisas pasarle parametros a la función, pero tampoco podés dejar los paréntesis porque se ejecuta directamente sin esperar el click.
O sea que así está bien: onClick={previousPhrase} en caso de necesitar pasar argumentos si utilizas como lo tenías originalmente.

Por último en el previousPhrase deberías hacerlo pasar a 3 si contador === 0 (esto estaba mal)

```
const [contador, setContador] = useState(0);
  const previousPhrase = () => {
      contador === 0 ? setContador(3) : setContador(--contador);
  };
  const nextPhrase = () => {
      contador === 3 ? setContador(0) : setContador(++contador);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <button type="button" onClick={previousPhrase}>Atrás</button>
      <button type="button" onClick={nextPhrase}>Adelante</button>
     <div>{contador}</div>
    </div>
  );
```